# Can't stop NHibernate from writing log to console in unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nhibernate

I have some unit tests that work with nhibernate on a local database.

I do not always need the `show_sql` output, so mostly I want to deactivate it. But no matter how I set the property, either in the `App.config` of the test project

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string_name">test</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <mapping assembly="MyLib"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Or via the configuration in the test classes

```
_logger.Info("Configuring NHibernate");
_configuration = new Configuration().Configure();
_configuration.SetProperty("nhibernate.show_sql", "false");
_sessionFactory = _configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
```

The console output **always** shows the SQL statements, cluttering up the console.

What am I missing? Do I set the value wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is yet another point where the output can be controlled; Directly at the methods!

```
SchemaExport export = new SchemaExport(_configuration);
export.Create(true, true);
```

The `Create` method provides two arguments:

```
bool useStdOut, bool execute
```

The first defines wether the SQL is written to standard output or not, and the second controls wether it is executed against the database.

From copy/pasting the tutorials, I always set both to true, which overwrote anything I configured earlier.

After setting it the first parameter to `false`, I no longer get the unwanted output.